# Decryptor for bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, encryption, bcrypt

The title is pretty self explanatory. I'm not sure if this exists, as it would greatly compromise the security of bcrypt, but i'm using Devise in a rails app and forgot my password. However I can access the server and find the info. I can see the encrypted password and need to decrypt it.

I do not want alternate solutions to the problem, i just want a decryptor so I can get the password.

Comment: I guess bruteforcing the password is what you can do...

Comment: If you don't want alternate solutions, you're not going to get any solutions. Bcrypt is a form of hashing, not encryption, so it's not reversible.

Comment: There are no known security flaws in bcrypt, otherwise nobody would use it. Set a new password as @tadman suggested. Bruteforcing is not a good idea, because bcrypt was made intentionally slow to prevent bruteforcing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you just spin up a Rails console and re-assign your password manually?

```
u = User.find_by_username('myname')
u.password = u.password_confirmation = 'reset_password'
u.save
```

Usually something along those lines will work.